# how can I make the title of FlexibleSpaceBar replace the title of the SliverAppBar when it starts to shrink via a user scroll

Tags: flutter

I have a `SliverAppBar` with a `title` and a `flexibleSpace` property which I assigned a `FlexibleSpaceBar` which also has its `title` property set. What I want to achieve is making the `FlexibleSpaceBar title` float up to where the `SliverAppBar's title` is while the `SliverAppBar's title` gradually fades out making the `FlexibleSpaceBar's title` be the only one available. But presently the `SliverAppBar's title` still stays on screen and the `FlexibleSpaceBar's title` overlaps it (Video representation below).

[image: Over here in the video you can see the FlexibleSpaceBar's title "Charity" overlapping the title "Home"]

Here is my Code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text('HOME',),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          pinned: true,
          stretchTriggerOffset: 10,
          onStretchTrigger: () async{
            print('hello');
            return;
          },
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
              child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            )
          ],
          expandedHeight: 120,
          flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('Charity',style:
            TextStyle(fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white),),
            stretchModes: [
              StretchMode.fadeTitle
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ];
    },
    body: const Text("this is good"),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

How can I hide the **Home** title when the **Charity** title floats up?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the effect by using `background` instead of `title` like so

```dart
background: SizedBox(
    height: 100,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        'Charity',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

The only issue is probably gonna be with alignment. The icon you have on the right might complicate things a bit. There are other solutions, but you have to dig through the framework code to get inspired with how they are pulling these effects off.